# Assigning items to containers

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables for separate things: One table for `containers`, one table for `items`. They both have things like descriptions, title, and of course ID fields: `container_ID` and `item_ID`.

My containers will need to have items assigned to them. Say each container will hold 5 - 25 items. However some items can possibly be in multiple containers.

I am thinking the easiest would be to make a table, call it for example assignment, and it has it's own ID, and then the container ID and the item ID.

```
CREATE TABLE `assignment` (
  `assignment_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `container_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `item_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`assignment_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `assignment_ID_UNIQUE` (`assignment_ID` ASC));
```

When we want to pull up one container (for example with the ID 5) we do this

```
SELECT item_ID FROM assignment WHERE container_ID = '5'
```

and we'd have all the items that belong to the one container.

I am wondering if this would be an efficient way of doing it, or am I setting myself up for trouble? Is this design scale-able? What else should I keep in mind?

Comment: You don't need both a primary and a unique constraint on `assignment_id`. In fact, you don't even need the column at all. A unique (or PK) constraint on `(container_id, item_id)` should suffice. (I assume that the same item cannot belong to the same container twice.)

Comment: I didn't know you could make a unique contraint on a combination of fields, thanks for that, I'll research some more on that! I have gotten in the habbit of giving each table unique IDs because phpMyAdmin wouldn't work otherwise... :D

Comment: That's a "many-to-many" mapping table.  You probably want the index going the other way, as well:  `INDEX(item_ID, conatiner_id)` -- this is so you can also start with a container and find what items are in it.